# Gebrauch des Jugendwortes des Jahres 2018 („Ehrenmann“) in Bezug auf die Mafia

Tags: teen-slang

Zum [Jugendwort des Jahres 2018](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugendwort_des_Jahres_(Deutschland)) wurde der Begriff „Ehrenmann“ beziehungsweise „Ehrenfrau“ gekürt, der einen freundlichen Menschen beziehungsweise jemand besonderen beschreiben soll und somit als eine Art Ersatz für das englische „Gentleman“ und „Lady“ dient.

Der Begriff „Ehrenmann“ war mir aber schon vor dem Jahre 2018 bekannt und ist keine Erfindung „der Jugend von heute“. Gehört habe ich ihn aber immer nur in Bezug auf die (italienische (und vielleicht auch die 1920er- bis 1940er-Jahre US-amerikanische)) Mafia (Beispiel [1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosa_Nostra), [2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Brusca) und [3](http://www.bornpower.de/mafia/ita-aufbau.htm)).

---

**Meinung:**

Mir persönlich drängt sich der Eindruck auf, als stamme das Jugendwort des Jahres 2018 aus dieser Ecke, auch wenn vielen, die dieses Wort gebrauchen, diese Verbindung gar nicht bewusst sein mag und der eigentliche Ursprung des Wortes möglicherweise anderswo liegt.

Dass sich Handlanger des organisierten Verbrechens untereinander als „Ehrenmänner“ titulieren und diese angeblich „ehrerbietige Bezeichnung“ auch von denjenigen „einfordern“, die sie einschüchtern und mit dem Tode bedrohen, ist nicht nur grotesk, sondern nimmt auch noch viel absonderlichere Züge an, wenn die Eingeschüchterten und Bedrohten es am Ende auch noch wirklich für „ehrenhaft“ halten, das Leben eines Mafioso zu führen.

Abgesehen von der italienischen Mafia ist dieser Begriff, glaube ich, auch immer wieder in bestimmten Reihen des deutschen Gangster-Rap und dessen durchaus realen Halbweltverbindungen aufgetaucht, wobei er in einem ebenso grotesken Ausmaße wie in Bezug auf die italienische Mafia verwendet wird. Und hier, vermute ich, setzt die ganze Sache an. Hierüber ist der Begriff wahrscheinlich in die Jugendsprache gelangt.

---

Könnte ich mit meiner Einschätzung richtig liegen? Wurde der Begriff (früher) **hauptsächlich** in Bezug auf mafiöse Strukturen gebraucht? Und woher kommt der Begriff ursprünglich und welche Bedeutung hatte er damals?

Comment: Sicherlich relevanter Artikel der Welt zu der Geschichte des gewählten Jugendwortes: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.welt.de/kultur/article183976012/Jugendwort-des-Jahres-Was-Ehrenmann-mit-Bushido-verbindet.html Auch interessant ist der Anstieg der Nutzung des Wortes *Ehrenmann*, sichtbar in diesem [ngram-Graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ehrenmann%2C+Ehrenfrau&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CEhrenmann%3B%2Cc0), Mitte des 19ten Jahrhunderts. Interessanterweise wurde etwa in diesem Zeitraum auch die ...

Comment: ... [sizilianische Mafia *Cosa Nostra*](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosa_Nostra) gegründet, deren Mitglieder sich als *uomini d'onore* (=Ehrenmänner) betitelten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Wort *Ehrenmann* ist mir durchaus geläufig, aber hauptsächlich in der Bedeutung, die es dem tatsächlichen Wortsinn nach hat: Ein ehrenwerter Mann, bzw. ein Mann von Ehre.

Dass in einigen Filmen die Mitglieder der italienischen Mafia auch so genannt wurden ist mir natürlich auch bekannt, aber das habe ich immer als eine ein wenig sarkastische Nebenbedeutung des Wortes angesehen. Ein Ehrenmann war und ist für mich trotz dieser Filme nach wie vor jemand, der es wert ist, geehrt zu werden.

Siehe auch

- [Ein Ehrenmann, der nicht geehrt werden wollte](https://www.nachrichten.at/oberoesterreich/nachrufe/Ein-Ehrenmann-der-nicht-geehrt-werden-wollte;art86198,3089087)
  Nachruf auf einen beliebten Präsidenten eines Fußballklubs
- [Pullach trauert um guten Kammeraden und Ehrenmann](https://www.merkur.de/lokales/muenchen-lk/pullach-ort29321/pullach-trauert-um-guten-kameraden-und-ehrenmann-8218407.html)
  Nachruf auf einen angesehenen Feuerwehrmann
- [Ein Patriot und Ehrenmann](https://www.rollingpin.at/magazin/ausgaben/182/ein-patriot-und-ehrenmann/)
  Interview mit einem berühmten Koch, der für sein Lebenswerk ausgezeichnet wurde
- [Ein Ehrenmann aus Eritrea](http://www.neuepresse.de/Thema/Specials/NP-Serie-Fluechtlinge/Ein-Ehrenmann-aus-Eritrea)
  Bericht über einen Flüchtling, der sich integriert hat und sich in Deutschland eine Existenz aufbauen konnte.
- [Max Schmeling - der Ehrenmann](https://www.max-schmeling-stiftung.de/max-schmeling/der-ehrenmann)
  Kurze Würdigung des verstorbenen Boxers auf der Website der Stiftung, die seinen Namen trägt.